# WSS 3.0 - Can not display created custom template lists with web services

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, list, list-template

I have created a custom list from another list in sharepoint, it is saved into the "List Template Gallery" I need to get this new list template by using web services, but the .GetListTemplates method of lists does not retrieve the custom templates. How can I get the custom templates?, so then I can use it to create a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Web Service is the way to go - [Check this out](http://blogs.msdn.com/sridhara/archive/2008/06/07/getwebtemplate-web-method-does-not-return-addlist-web-method-does-not-recognize-my-custom-list-templates.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
string listName = "ListTemplateName";

foreach (SPListTemplate template in web.ListTemplates)
        {
            if (template.InternalName.Equals(internalName))
            {
                return template;
            }
        }
```

Comment: He said he's using web services, not the object model.

Comment: Sorry...missed that he needed it through a webservice call.

Comment: Yes, I need web services please

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this using this?

[MSDN][1]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd586523(office.11).aspx

It should retrieve all the lists including the List Template Gallery, wich is hidden...